# How can I get the size of an object in react three fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I want to resize a certain object in react three fiber based upon the size of another object. I have loaded the 2 objects using the STL loader and wanna use these.

```
const geomUpper = useLoader(STLLoader, upperUrl)
const geomLower = useLoader(STLLoader, lowerUrl)
```

Then I want to use the size of geomUpper to resize geomLower but I don't know how to get the size of geomUpper. Is there a way to get its size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Inside of an effect hook, you can get the size of `geomUpper` and use it to scale `geomLower`.

```
function Scene() {
  const geomUpper = useLoader( STLLoader, '/upper.stl' );
  const geomLower = useLoader( STLLoader, '/lower.stl' );

  useEffect(() => {

    if ( ! geomUpper.boundingSphere ) {
      geomUpper.computeBoundingSphere();
    }
    console.log( 'geomUpper radius', 
      geomUpper.boundingSphere.radius );

    if( ! geomLower.boundingSphere ) {
      geomLower.computeBoundingSphere();
    }
    console.log( 'geomLower radius', 
      geomLower.boundingSphere.radius );

    const scale = geomUpper.boundingSphere.radius / 
      geomLower.boundingSphere.radius;

    geomLower.scale( scale, scale, scale );
    console.log( 'geomLower radius (after scaling)', 
      geomLower.boundingSphere.radius );

  })

  return (
    <Suspense>
      <mesh geometry={geomUpper} />
      <mesh geometry={geomLower} />
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

I'm using the radius of the `boundingShere` here as a proxy for the size, but that's just for brevity.  You could use the *x*, *y*, and *z* dimensions of the `boundingBox` with more advanced logic that suits your needs.  My `console.log()` calls are just sanity checks and can be removed.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (won't work with React Three Fiber, but should work with vanilla Three.js)

This should work if geomUpper's position is inside its mesh(es).

```
// create a Box3 to hold the dimensions
// initialize it to a zero-size box at geomUpper's position
const bbox = new THREE.Box3(geomUpper.position, geomUpper.position);

// expand the box to include geomUpper's children
// expandByObject mutates bbox
bbox.expandByObject(geomUpper);

// get the size of bbox
let size = new THREE.Vector3();
bbox.getSize(size);
```

Comment: I have tried this code but now it says on the expandByObject line that 'object.updateWorldMatrix is not a function at Box3.expandByObject'. I red that this could happen because geomUpper, loaded by STLLoader is a JSON file containing data about the STL file and not a Object3D, Does three fiber have a loader that loads stl files as Object3D and not a JSON file?
https://imgur.com/DW3Qbt5

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, maybe simpler to use is to compute the bounding box of the object and to get the size.

```
// Compute the bounding box
const bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(objectRef.current)
// Init your size variable
const bboxSize = new THREE.Vector3(bbox)
// Get the size
bbox.getSize(bboxSize)
// Now use bboxSize (x,y,z)
```